# How can I resolve "(Service check did not exit properly)" and "(null)" results with my services?

Tags: nagios, debian-wheezy

I'm using some Perl-based scripts for service checks in Nagios and I get `(Service check did not exit properly)` and `(null)` as the result in Nagios, but the script works great on the command line.

I've seen solutions online suggesting to disable the internal Perl interpreter by setting `enable_embedded_perl=0` in the Nagios configuration or by specifying the path to an interpreter explicitly. This did not help with the issue.

What else could it be?

Comment: Can you show an example of how it "works great" via CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Perl scripts from the Nagios Exchange will try to include the `utils.pm` Perl module. You'll find a line like this somewhere in it:

```
use lib "/usr/local/nagios/libexec";
```

When installing Nagios on Debian, the default location of the `utils.pm` file is `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/utils.pm`. So the `use lib` directive should be:

```
use lib "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins";
```

Executing the command from the command line most likely worked because you were in `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/`, editing your plugin.

Answer (score 11):

[Nagios includes its own embedded perl interpreter.](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/embeddedperl.html) Your plugin is probably not epn compliant.

You might want to disable it globally, or just disable it for your script. The bottom of that docs page shows you how to do this.

Basically, add `# nagios: -epn` on its own line somewhere within the first ten lines of your script. This should fix your problem.

You could also [make it compliant](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/epnplugins.html), but it's almost certainly not worth the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. Even though I explicitly stated that this did not have any impact on the specific problem I was facing.

Comment: This is real resolve for nagios. without -epn, plugin is included and executed internally by nagios. with -epn, it is loaded as external executable, similar to binaries or bash scripts. See page: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/embeddedperl.html  and consider epn complaint

Comment: The colon is required in `# nagios: -epn`, per the docs and per my tests.

Comment: Strangely enough, the current Ubuntu LTS (18.04) version of nagios-plugins-standard (2.2-3ubuntu2) has this issue. Things work if I either modify affected plugins, eg `check_disk_smb` and `check_file_age`, or if I set ```use_embedded_perl_implicitly=0```

Comment: Fixed it for me! Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Prefix the command with `/usr/bin/perl`.

This solution is more of a workaround, it's probably not a good idea to do so but at least your plugin should work the same way it does when you launch it from the terminal.

NOTE: In my experience `# nagios -epn` works quite often, but sometimes it doesn't seem to be enough. I noticed that when this happens, the faulty plugins reports many warnings (when the script is invoked with `perl -w`).